# Unknown display + no sound on upgrading kernel to 4.18 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, audio, display, realtek

I am running a Dell [Optiplex 7060](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/optiplex-7060-desktop/docs) with Ubuntu 18.04 (dual-booted with Windows). The system only has Intel's iGPU (UHD Graphics 630) to which I have two monitors connected, and it uses the Realtek ALC3234 audio controller.

Both monitors and the sound were working without issue with the kernel `4.15.0-54-generic` until I decided to update to kernel version `4.18` for work reasons. I installed the packages `linux-image-4.15.0-25-generic` and `linux-modules-4.15.0-25-generic`.

Now, whenever I log into Ubuntu with the kernel 4.18, the second monitor does not work, and the settings shows "Unknown display". Further, there is no audio, only showing the Dummy Output. [image]

I have tried booting into the older kernel (4.15) and everything still works. 
Unlike [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479820/sound-issues-after-recent-4-18-kernel-on-spectre-x360) thread, there are no errors in `dmesg`. The kernel option `nomodeset` has no effect.
I have tried deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

For the audio issue,

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
```

None of these steps have had any effect towards fixing this problem. Interestingly, I had experienced this same problem when I had Ubuntu 16.04 installed on this system (a year back).

`ubuntu-drivers devices` does not show any devices requiring special drivers.

Any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: May I suggest for troubleshoot purposes only you create a LiveUSB with Ubuntu 19.04 http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.04/ which uses the 5.0 kernel https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes and see if you can replicate the problem, or if it works?

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C audio` and `sudo lshw -C multimedia` as well as `uname -a` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by installing the following packages:

- linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-25-generic
- linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
- linux-headers-4.18.0-25
- linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic
- linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
- linux-generic-hwe-18.04

The extra headers obviously didn't help, so it is one of `linux-modules-extra`, `linux-image-generic-hwe` or `linux-generic-hwe`.

Both `linux-image-generic-hwe` and `linux-generic-hwe` only have a changelog and a copyright notice. [Source](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/linux-generic-hwe-16.04/filelist). The fix, therefore, must be from one of the modules shipped with `linux-modules-extra`.

The [LTSEnablementStack/HardwareEnablement(HWE)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) packages seem to be really responsible.

Comment: I spent some time trying to isolate which were the modules responsible, but I was unable to isolate any